# Comparar 2 fechas para poder traer el documento mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Hola estoy intentando consultar en la base de datos mongoDB por estos dos campos

createdAt  y updatedAt

Necesito que solo me traiga los documentos donde updatedAt > createdAt, estoy usando mongoose pero no pudo lograr esta validación. Se buscara en base al updatedAt, es decir si le mando fechaInicial: 2022-11-16T14:22:47.277+00:00 fechaFinal: 2022-11-16T20:22:47.277+00:00 solo me debe traer los documentos donde el updatedAt este entre esas 2 fechas y que el createdAt sea menor al updatedAt.

Por ejemplo un documento con estos valores en esos campos:

createdAt: 2022-11-15T20:37:28.629+00:00
updatedAt: 2022-11-16T14:22:47.277+00:00

Como se puede notar el updatedAt es posterior al createdAt entonces me tendria que traer ese documento.

```
db.find({
        updatedAt: {
          $gt: fechaSolicitudInicial,
          $lt: fechaSolicitudFinal,
        }})
```

Solo pudo traer los documentos que están entre las dos fechas que le enviaron, pero no pudo validar si el createdAt es inferior al updatedAt

Comment: que valores tienen `fechaSolicitudInicial` y `fechaSolicitudFinal`?

Comment: Son dinámicos, es depende de lo que queramos consultar, prodian ser:
fechaSolicitudInicial:  2022-11-16T00:00:00.277+00:00
fechaSolicitudFinal: 2022-11-16T19:22:47.277+00:00

Comment: Si, supongo que son "inputs" del usuario... pero como los procesas para luego mandarlos en la consulta?

Comment: Los envio como parametros en postman

Comment: Lo que estoy suponiendo es que esas fechas las estás mandando como "string", por lo tanto la consulta en mongo no te funciona... los debes enviar como fechas

Comment: Si funciona, lo que necesito es agregarle la validacion de que solo traiga los documentos donde updatedAt sea mayor a createdAt

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140783/discussion-between-juan-jose-and-pipe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entonces deberías poder usar `$expr`, algo así:

```
db.find({
    updatedAt: {
       $gt: fechaSolicitudInicial,
       $lt: fechaSolicitudFinal,
    },
    $expr:{ $gt:["$updatedAt", "$createdAt"]}  //Donde updatedAt sea mayor a createdAt dentro del mismo documento
})
```

Comment: Si me funciono muchas gracias.

Comment: Que bien, saludos